# Scrollable Layout on top of ViewPager

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-viewpager, scrollable

I am creating an app with an AppBar and below this one, a (Relative)Layout.

Like in Facebook Messenger :

[image]

You can see the AppBar and below it a Layout with three buttons (TOUS, MESSENGER, SMS).

When I scroll, my Layout including the three buttons does not move, it stays "pinned" at the same position (on top). My objective is to make that the Layout with the thress buttons pass behind the AppBar and does not stay in the view.

Here is my actual code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/fullWhite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="@color/background_grey_white">

        <!-- These part has to scroll and pass behind the AppBar when the user is scrolling, but it does not work at the moment, it stays "pinned" at the top of the screen -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="13sp"
            android:id="@+id/content_frame">
            <include layout="@layout/tous_messenger_sms"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/separator_color"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

What do I have to change to make it work ?

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just move the **RelativeLayout** into the layout of the first element of the **ViewPager**. In this way when you swipe, the elements in the **RelativeLayout** will disappear, because the current tab was changed.

Comment: Following this way, the RelativeLayout will pass behind the AppBar when I scroll down the screen ?

Comment: If the layout for the first tab in the **ViewPager** is scrollable and you swipe down, yes! It will pass behind the AppBar. If you swipe right, it will disappear from the screen, because the current tab will be the second one.